# Как сокращать строку в UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c

Надо в UIAlertController со стилем UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet выводить строчки все с одним шрифтом, а если она очень длинная, то не уменьшать размер шрифта, а сокращать через троеточее. Сейчас уменьшается шрифт, а если этого не достаточно, то троеточее в середине.

Есть какой-то способ это изменить?

Comment: нет такого способа. надо либо писать свой либо наследовать и ковыряться

Comment: Пришлось просто делать ограничение на длину строки, и если она его превышает, выставлять в конце троеточее. Пока так.